# Listview items are not listed proper

Tags: android, android-layout

As you see in the given image, table is not showing properly, columns are not in proper way, some has small width and has large. I also try maxwidth and minwidth, but its not working.
I am using the listview, because the list is generated dynamically so i use adapter for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linear_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Size_40"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_sn_no"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_30"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_30"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_30"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:text="Sno"
            android:textColor="@color/rms_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:background="#8B9594" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_item_name"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_80"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_80"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_80"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:text="Item Name"
            android:textColor="@color/rms_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:background="#8B9594" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headingfood_type"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_70"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_70"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_70"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Food Type"
            android:textColor="@color/rms_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/txt_food_type"
            style="@style/SpinnerAsEditText"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_70"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_70"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_70"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/food_type_array"
            android:prompt="@string/food_type"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:background="#8B9594" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_qnty"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:text="Qty"
            android:textColor="@color/rms_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12"
            android:editable="true" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:background="#8B9594" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_rate"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_35"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_35"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_35"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:text="Rate"
            android:textColor="@color/rms_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:background="#8B9594" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_amount"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_45"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_45"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_45"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textColor="@color/rms_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:background="#8B9594" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_cancel"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/rms_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Margin_5"
            android:background="#8B9594" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_check"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sendtokitchen"
            android:textColor="@color/rms_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkbox"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/Size_40"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/Size_40" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Here is the image link.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/6GVNB.png

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how you should be implementing listviews/tables. Look at these:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

I assume the code you have supplied is the single row item that gets put into the listview tag?
This isn't quite an answer I know, but I currently can't comment.